# pyRevit Profile keeps changing

Tags: pyrevit

First I'm not the user using this but am implementing it for a couple of users.

We use VDi machines with all users profiles on the server.  I have managed to clone the Git Repo and leave a copy on the server which I use Robo copy to copy to the users.

This has worked great but we are facing an issue when they want to change some settings we get an error. The Setting do work great if in the config file it is pointing to the UNC path (\domian.local\share\users\username) but if it points to the drive lette of the share (t:\users\username) or c drive (c:\users\username) we get an error.

I'll look for the errors and upload it.

Cheers
Isaac

Comment: Issac would you mind reporting the issue on the git issue tracker and add screen caps from your errors? https://github.com/eirannejad/pyRevit/issues